# How to draw image from image source in Zendpdf in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, pdf, zend-framework

I am trying to create a packing slip for delhivery. An APi from delhivery send the details of packing slip including the Barcode source.

> $barcodeImage =
>   data:image/png;base64,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

This is the data I am getting from delhivery for waybill number barcode image. When I paste it in browser url the image is displayed correctly. But I am not understanding how to add the image in packing slip pdf using zend pdf. I used the following codes, but still it is not showing up properly.

```
$page->drawText($barcodeImage, 35, ($top -= 30));

$page->drawImage($barcodeImage, $x1, $y1, $x1+30, $y1+15);

$image_barcode = "<img src='".barcodeImage."'>";
$page->drawImage($image_barcode, $x1, $y1, $x1+30, $y1+15);
```

Answer (score 0):

Save barcode image on the server and after that use it.

```
$data = base64_decode($barcodeImage);

file_put_contents('image.png', $data);

$image_barcode = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath('image.png');

$page->drawImage($image_barcode,$x1, $y1, $x1+30, $y1+15);
```

Comment: please go thorugh this link "https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/250625/sql-error-while-adding-any-products-to-category-m2" if you have idea reply me