# sql error while adding any products to category : M2

Tags: magento2, database, category-products

> Something went wrong while saving the category.SQLSTATE[23000]:
>   Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row:
>   a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`mydb`.`catalog_category_product`, CONSTRAINT
>   `CAT_CTGR_PRD_PRD_ID_SEQUENCE_PRD_SEQUENCE_VAL` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`product_id`) REFERENCES `sequence_product` (`sequence_value`) ON
>   DELETE CA), query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_category_product`
>   (`category_id`,`product_id`,`position`) VALUES (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?),
>   (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?)

Getting this error when trying to add any product to category.

I have already try with re-indexing, url regenerate, but still not working.

Comment: let me know magento 2 version?

Comment: have you installed (or) override any custom modules related to products or categories? did you do any customization related to products/ categories?

Comment: Magento ver. 2.1.14, I haven't don't any customization. Ihave also try to disable all custom modules, but still not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the product and create it again.