# Magento2 save Custom shipment field by API

Tags: magento2, api, shipment, shipment-tracking

I have add field `track_url` in table `sales_shipment_track`.
I'm creating shipment with API

```
http://192.168.0.105/magento2/project/rest/V1/order/1292/ship


{
  "items": [
    {
      "order_item_id": 4473,
      "qty": 1
    }
  ],
  "notify": true,
  "tracks": [
    {
      "track_number": "3456789",
      "track_url": "http://192.168.0.105/demo/magento2?gf=13131",
      "title": "GEODIS",
      "carrier_code": "custom"
    }
  ]
}
```

everything was working fine before added new field track_url.

Now i'm getting error.
"message": "Property \"`TrackUrl`\" does not have corresponding setter in `class \"Magento\\Sales\\Api\\Data\\ShipmentTrackCreationInterface\`".",

How can i add extension attribute for it?
**EDIT**
I have add attribute in `extension_attributes.xml`.How can i save it with `API`?

```
    <config>
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface">
        <attribute code="dpd_relay_id" type="string"/>
        <attribute code="erp_exported" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>

    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface">
        <attribute code="finalprice" type="string"/>
        <attribute code="brand" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>

     <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentTrackCreationInterface">
        <attribute code="track_url" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>

</config>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with below request payload

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "order_item_id": 4473,
      "qty": 1
    }
  ],
  "notify": true,
  "tracks": [
    {
      "track_number": "3456789",
      "title": "GEODIS",
      "carrier_code": "custom",
      "extension_attributes" : {
            "track_url": "http://192.168.0.105/demo/magento2?gf=13131"
      }
    }
  ]
}.
```

You need to update extension_attributes.xml file as well. As you have not defined the xsd in config node.

```
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface">
        <attribute code="dpd_relay_id" type="string"/>
        <attribute code="erp_exported" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>

    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface">
        <attribute code="finalprice" type="string"/>
        <attribute code="brand" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>

     <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentTrackCreationInterface">
        <attribute code="track_url" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>

</config>
```

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: I need one more help please go this link "magento.stackexchange.com/questions/250625/… you have any idea reply me

Comment: @Saniya, Where's Link !!!!

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/250625/sql-error-while-adding-any-products-to-category-m2

Comment: "message": "Property \"TrackUrl\" does not have corresponding setter in class \"Magento\\Sales\\Api\\Data\\ShipmentTrackCreationExtensionInterface\".",

getting this error

Comment: I am guessing you are on developer mode so just remove generated folder then check and before that update your question with complete extension_attribute.xml file and location.

Comment: i have updated my answer

Comment: I also updated my answer.

Comment: getting same error still

Comment: is this right ? extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentTrackCreationInterface

Comment: open this file generated/code/Magento/Sales/Api/Data/ShipmentTrackCreationExtensionInterface and check if there are any getter setter of defined attribute. If not then try to compile code once.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86132/discussion-between-ketan-borada-and-ramkishan-suthar).

Comment: Did you manage to get this working and saving custom attributes to shipment track table?